# <ul> positioned at bottom of parent <div>

Tags: jquery, html, css

I built a jQuery dropdown menu using elements with `position: absolute`, and a `<ul>` inside of the menu is located near the bottom, rather than at the top of this dropdown. Here is a Snippet displaying the webpage. The problem `<ul>` is in blue text (click on the image):

```js
function main() {
  $('#arrow').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').animate({
      top: '200px'
    }, 400);

    $('#slide-wrapper').animate({
      marginTop: '250px'
    }, 400);

    $(this).attr('src','uparrow.jpg');

    $(this).off();

    $(this).click(function(){
      $('.hidden').animate({
        top: '-=250'
      }, 400);

      $('#slide-wrapper').animate({
        marginTop: '0px'
      }, 400);

      $(this).attr('src','downarrow.jpg');

      $(this).off();

      main();
    });

  });
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

/* Menu elements */

.hidden {
  z-index: -5;
  top: -50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#arrow {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
}

#arrow-box {
  background-color: white; /* FOR NOW */
}

#banner {
  background-color: gray; /* For now, until I get some pictures in */
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#dropdown {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.menu {
  float: left;
  color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}

/* Fonts and such */

h1 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
}

.unstyled {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* General structural elements */

#content {
  width: 75%;
  height: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

#slide-wrapper {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
}

/* Footer stuff */

footer {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: gray; /* FOR NOW */
}

#footer-border {
  background-color: black; /* Probably dark blue later */
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fields {
  float: right;
  padding: 2px;
}

label {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#message {
  height: 150px;
}

#contact {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 250px;
}

input, textarea {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}

.button {
  width: auto;
}

#copy {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="banner">
      <h1>Company Name Placeholder</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="dropdown" class="hidden">
      <ul class="menu hidden unstyled">
        <li class="menu">Home</li>
        <li class="menu">About Me</li>
        <li class="menu">Get a Website</li>
        <li class="menu">Portfolio</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="arrow-box">
      <img id="arrow" src="downarrow.jpg"/>
    </div>
  <div id="slide-wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      Page content will go here.
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer-border"></div>
        <div class="left">
          This will be about customers contacting me, etc.
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <form id="contact" method="post" action"mail.php" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <ul class="fields unstyled">
              <li class="fields"><label for="name">Full Name</label><input name="name" type="text" maxlength=50 placeholder="Your Name" required=""></input></li>
              <li class="fields"><label for="email-address">E-Mail</label><input type="email" name="email-address" maxlength=50 placeholder="you@example.com" required=""></input></li>
              <li class="fields"><label for="subject">Subject</label><input name="subject" type="text" maxlength=50 required=""></input></li>
              <li class="fields"><label for="message">Message</label><textarea id="message" name="message" maxlength=1000 required=""></textarea></li>
              <li class="fields"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit"></input></li>
            </ul>
          </form>
        </div>
        <p id="copy">&copy; 2015 - Evan Dempsey</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
    <!-- Scripts down here -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="menu.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: question is not clear. can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Is the problem the `top` value of 200px that the JavaScript puts in?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your .hidden css jQuery:

```
$('#arrow').click(function(){
$('.hidden').animate({
  top: '200px'
}, 400);
```

This will give all elements with class "hidden" the top:200px, and it gives both to your "dropdown" and your text below

To fix it, simply replace ".hidden" with your id ("#dropdown") and give some top:50px to your ul below.

[Working fiddle example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/htby2f4a/1)

And of course you have to change your closing animation as well:

```
$(this).click(function(){
  $('#dropdown').animate({
    top: '-=250'
  }, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you're looking for an answer using jQuery but the same thing can be accomplished using CSS and, depending on your situation, it may be easier to implement than loading scripts. This works by linking a hidden checkbox to the dropdown menu.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/87dbmcj4/

HTML:

```
<input type='checkbox' id='button'>
<label for='button'>
    Toggle Dropdown
</label>
<div class='dropdown'>
    Insert menu here.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0 20px;
    transition: max-height 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

:checked ~ .dropdown {
    max-height: 200px; /* Set to anything larger than your menu */
}
```